Finding Polish 1921 census records of town called Wola Raniżowska
Where can I find the Polish 1921 census records of a town called Wola Raniżowska?
My grandmother immigrated to the USA from there.

Contemporary information
To find information from the 1921 census, we first need to place Wola Raniżowska on the contemporary administrative map.
Wola Raniżowska currently is in the podkarpackie voivodeship. In 1921, it would be in the Lwów voivodeship, Kolbuszowa powiat, Raniszów gmina. Now we know where to find it in the census.
Current access
Centralna Biblioteka Statystyczna contains scans, although seemingly without OCR, of the 1921 census. The Lwów voivodeship is contained in this link. However, we can see that it does stop at the level of powiat, thus not answering your question.
However, in the table of contents there is another source that could help us - Skorowidz miejscowości Rzeczypospolitej Polskiej opracowany na podstawie wyników Pierwszego Powszechnego Spisu Ludności z dn. 30 września 1921 r. i innych źródeł urzędowych. - a locality index available e.g. under this link.
The desired locality is on page 19. Here is the relevant excerpt, translated by me and adapted to SE's table limitations:



Miasta, Gminy, Obszary dworskie
Budynki z przeznaczeniem mieszkalnym
Budynki inne zamieszkałe
Ludność ogółem
Ludność - Mężczyźni
Ludność - Kobiety
Wyznanie - rzymskokatolickie
Wyznanie - greckokatolickie
Wyznanie - ewangelickie
Wyznanie - inne chrześcijańskie
Wyznanie - mojżeszowe
Wyznanie - inne
Wyznanie - niewiadome
Narodowość - polska
Narodowość - rusińska
Narodowość - niemiecka
Narodowość - żydowska
Narodowość - inna
Narodowość - niewiadoma




Cities, counties, manors
Buildings of residential purpose
Other dwellings
Total population
Men
Women
Roman Catholics
Greek Catholics
Protestants
Other Christians
Jews (faith)
Other faiths
Unknown faith
Poles
Ruthenians
Germans
Jews (nationality)
Other nationality
Unknown nationality


55. Wola Raniżowska
632
-
3556
1741
1815
3454
-
12
-
90
-
-
3522
-
9
25
-
-



As you can see, it is very general - no detailed records of trades, etc. This is all I have currently found.
